# Why is my code for 'mat-form-field' not working?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm totaly new to angular, and i was practicing using material and adding form fields. I followed all the guides, downloaded all the packages and my code is just copy-pased from a guide but it's still not displaying on my browser.

My console initialy showed

"Unexpected directive 'MatFormField' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation."

and after googling it I was told to replace it with "MatFormFieldModule" but after i did i got this error

"NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CdkObserveContent -> ElementRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CdkObserveContent -> ElementRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!"

My code:

**app.component.html**

```
    <p>works</p>
    <form class = "tp-form">
      <mat-form-field class = "tp-full-width">
         <input matInput placeholder = "Favorite Food" value = "Pasta">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class = "tp-full-width">
         <textarea matInput placeholder = "Enter your comment"></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class = "tp-full-width">
         <input matInput placeholder = "Email" [formControl] = 
    "emailFormControl">
         <mat-error *ngIf = "emailFormControl.hasError('email') 
            && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Please enter a valid email address
         </mat-error>
         <mat-error *ngIf = "emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Email is <strong>required</strong>
         </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { CourseComponent } from './course/course.component';

    import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform- 
    browser/animations';
    import {MatInputModule, MatFormField, MatFormFieldModule} from 
    '@angular/material'
    import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

    import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

    const modules =  [
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
          MatInputModule,
          FormsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          MatFormFieldModule

    ]

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CourseComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
          ...modules
      ],
      exports:[
        ...modules
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      ,
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
    import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'materialApp';
       emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.email,
      ]);
    }
```

Currently my browser is only showing "works".

Comment: You didn't replace the import as stated as MatFormField is still included in your imports. Remove it.

Comment: Its in the imports at the top but not in @NgModule. I removed it from the imports at the top but it didnt change anything

Comment: Your code works perfectly, and shouldn't even have `MatFormFieldModule` imported. Please recreate the issue by forking this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wrd3c?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by reinstalling material in the projects directory

Answer (score 0):

`emailFormControl` should be define with `ViewChild` annotation, like this:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'

...

@ViewChild('emailFormControl') emailFormControl: ElementRef
```

In short, `ViewChild` allows us to query elements (from the docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

In this example we used the query target our `emailFormControl` an get a valid reference